# Unordered pair of proper classes

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

The usual Kuratowski ordered pair function does not work on proper classes, because if $A,B$ are proper classes and $\langle A,B\rangle=\{\{A\},\{A,B\}\}$, then since $A\notin\{A\}$ and so on you get $\langle A,B\rangle=\{\emptyset\}$, which is not very useful. Instead, you can use a definition like $(A,B)=(\{0\}\times A)\cup(\{1\}\times B)$ where $0,1$ are any two distinct sets and $A\times B$ is the set of all (Kuratowski) ordered pairs of elements from $A,B$, from which you can extract the elements as $A=\{x:\langle 0,x\rangle\in(A,B)\}$ and similarly for $B$.

Now that process all works perfectly fine, but now I'm interested in defining an *unordered* pair of the proper classes $A,B$, which is to say a definable term $[A,B]$ which satisfies $$[A,B]=[C,D]\iff(A=C\wedge B=D)\vee(A=D\wedge B=C)$$

for any classes $A,B,C,D$. I don't see any easy way to build this from the above ordered pair definition; does anyone have an idea for such a formula?

Bonus points if you can generalize to an unordered set: given an index set $x$ (not a proper class) and a definable class term $A_i$ with free variable $i$, define a term $[A_i:i\in x]$ which satisfies $$[A_i:i\in x]=[B_j:j\in x]\iff \exists \sigma:x\overset{bij.}{\to} x.\forall i\in x.A_i=B_{\sigma(i)}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[A, B] = \{\{A\cap V_\alpha, B\cap V_\alpha\}: \alpha\in On\}$ will do the trick. To see this, let $[A, B] = [C, D]$ and suppose $A\not = C, D$. Then there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $A\cap V_\alpha \not = C\cap V_\alpha, D\cap V_\alpha$. So $\{A\cap V_\alpha, B\cap V_\alpha\} \not = \{C\cap V_\alpha, D\cap V_\alpha\}$  contradicting our assumption that $[A, B] = [C, D]$. It follows from this argument that if $[A, B] = [C, D]$, then $(A = C \wedge B = D) \vee (A = D \wedge B = C)$. The other direction is trivial.

Comment: This is, essentially, $(A\cup B)\times\{0,1\}$.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Can you reconstruct $A$ and $B$ from this class?

Comment: In what sense can we reconstruct sets $a$ and $b$ from $\{a, b\}$? In any case, I'm pretty sure it satisfies the required condition. Is it worth spelling this out?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, of course.

Comment: I think I believe you, but do you have a proof for the forward direction? (Also, for the proof it might be simpler if you just made that a function on $On$ instead of an image set.)

Comment: @Asaf, @ GME You can meaningfully reconstruct $a$ from $\{a,b\}$ if you phrase it as "what is the element of $\{a,b\}$ that contains $x$" where $x$ is some element of $a\setminus b$. If that set is empty (and the converse is too) then there is nothing to distinguish in the first place.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Good. That sense is available here too. If $x\in A\setminus B$, then $A$ is the union of elements in the paris of $[A, B]$ which contain $x$.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you need that image set to be a function to deduce $\{A\cap V_\alpha,B\cap V_\alpha\}\ne\{C\cap V_\alpha,D\cap V_\alpha\}\to[A,B]\ne[C,D]$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Sorry, I'm not following. Which step do you think is wrong? (In particular, I'm unsure what you mean by "image set" and its being a function in this context.)

Comment: Without more assumptions or properties of your pairs, it might be the case that $\{A\cap V_\alpha,B\cap V_\alpha\}\ne\{C\cap V_\alpha,D\cap V_\alpha\}$ but $\{A\cap V_\alpha,B\cap V_\alpha\}=\{C\cap V_\beta,D\cap V_\beta\}$ for some other $\beta$ and the image sets are equal under some shifting of the indexes. If it's a function then you can't shift the sets around like this.

Comment: An image set is a set of the form $\{f(x):x\in A\}$, which is the image of a function $f$ on $A$. An actual function would look like $\{\langle x,f(x)\rangle:x\in A\}$. For example, $\{x:x\in\Bbb Z\}=\{x+1:x\in\Bbb Z\}$ even though $x\ne x+1$.

Comment: @Mario, if $A\cap V_\alpha\ne C\cap V_\alpha,D\cap V_\alpha$, then $A\cap V_\beta\ne C\cap V_\beta, D\cap V_\beta$ for any $\beta>\alpha$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo But what about $A\cap V_\alpha\ne C\cap V_\beta, D\cap V_\beta$? (Note: this is probably correct, but my point was that it's not as immediate as it would have been with a function since the index ordinal is right there.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Yes, that also holds. Look, if $\alpha$ not being explicit somehow bothers you, you can change $[A,B]$ to be $\{(\alpha,\{A\cap V_\alpha,B\cap V_\alpha\})\mid\alpha\in\mathsf{ORD}\}$. (It is just a minor cosmetic change, but perhaps you find this version clearer.)

Comment: One last remark, for the "bonus points": the set $\{\{A_i\cap V_\alpha:i\in x\}:\alpha\in On\}$ satisfies the requirements because since $y\in A_i\setminus A_j$ implies that some $\alpha$ has $y\in (A_i\cap V_\alpha)\setminus (A_j\cap V_\alpha)$, there is an $\alpha$ that separates every pair $i,j$ with $A_i\ne A_j$ (since the collection of all such pairs is a set), and the proof proceeds as above.