# Class defined by class in ZFC

Tags: set-theory

I'm new in ZFC set theory and I studied that a class C in ZFC is only a logic formula. I have seen in some posts (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063619/unordered-pair-of-proper-classes)) this: {C}.
My question is: if {C} means $\{x : x \in C\}$ then {C}=C?
I think I'm wrong but I don't understand where.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear; in the linked post we have e.g. $\alpha \in \text {On}$ and we know that $\text {On}$ is a proper *class* and not a set. This is the same as writing $\text{On}(\alpha)$.

Comment: See also [Class (set theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)).

Comment: In general, $\{ A \}$ means the set or class whose only member is $A$.

Comment: Thus, if $\mathcal C$ is a *class* we have (as you said): $\mathcal C = \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$ for some formula $\varphi$. And thus, $\{ \mathcal C \} = \{ y \mid y= \mathcal C \}$.

Comment: Ok I was wrong because {C} doesn't mean {x | x is in C} but {x | x=C}. Thank you.

Comment: if $C=\{x∣φ(x)\}$ we have $\{C\}=\{x | x=C\}=\{x∣ \forall y ( y∈x \leftrightarrow φ(y))\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\{C\}$ is the class whose only element is $C$, it is not $C$ itself. However, if $C$ is not a set, then $\{C\}$ is not a well-defined object *of the universe*.

The question you link asks about how to represent an ordered pair of two proper classes, exactly because we cannot write $\{\{A\},\{A,B\}\}$ when $A$ and $B$ are two classes.

Comment: the author says A∉{A} (but what is the meaning of A∈{A}?), A∉{A} maybe because A is not a set?

Comment: Yes, to say that $A\in\{A\}$ is only meaningful if $A$ is a set. If $A$ is not a set, then it literally makes no syntactic sense.